# How can I create a new menu entry for the panel for Lubuntu (LXDE)?

Tags: lubuntu, launcher, menu, lxde

On Lubuntu's panel, I can add the "Directory Menu". When clicked, instead of opening an app, it shows a menu (which in turn can open an app). See the image:

[image: Menu when clicking on "Directory Menu"]

---

**EDIT for clarification**

In the image, the desktop is blue. I have not clicked the menu icon (the blue bird on the far left), but instead the Directory Menu icon, where my cursor is showing. The menu below it (`bin`, `binConf`, …) belongs to that icon.

(The Directory Menu is added to the panel by going to Add/Remove Panel Items, and adding Directory Menu.)

---

I want to create my own menu icon (not for files, though). Having searched all over the place, I can find how to create new panel launchers, but not new panel menus.

How do I go about making such an entry for the Lubuntu panel?

Comment: Paddy, have you tried the How to here.  https://lkubaski.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/adding-lxde-start-menu-and-desktop-shortcuts/

Comment: @Rex Thank you, but this is for the main menu, not for a panel item menu. It's not quite what I'm after. I have edited my question to make clearer what was being clicked. (Incidentally, for the main menu, I have found it easier to use the GUI Menu Editor `menulibre`.)

Comment: "Directory Menu" is for quick directories navigation, you could add entries to the blue bird by coping `.desktop` files from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/` and editing them to your liking (add `Categories=` [see here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)), it is unclear for what the menu you want is

Comment: to change an lxpanel icon [see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028108/663954)

Comment: @ustick Thank you, but that's not actually what I'm after. Never mind, I suppose that it's not possible in Lubuntu. It was possible in Unity. But now Unity has gone and we have Gnome :)

Comment: `When clicked, instead of opening an app, it shows a menu`, you just want to open the file manager? see launchers (iirc), i think you have added the wrong item, from what i understood

Comment: @ustick My specific example is that I want to have an icon in the launcher for Gnome Terminal. In Unity, I could either click the launcher, and Gnome Terminal would load with the default profile; or I could right-click to get a list of different profiles that I had created, allowing me to quick-start Gnome Terminal with a specific profile. Hmm… you know, in hindsight, I should have led with that, shouldn't I? (Doh!)