# Lubuntu: How to change panel applet icon?

Tags: lubuntu, icons, panel, icon-themes, lxpanel

So I'm kinda new to Linux, just installed Lubuntu and love it.

I have this "minimize all windows" button in my panel (next to bluetooth, battery, wi-fi etc...) but it's kinda ugly and I'd like to give it a symbolic icon from the icon set I use so it matches the rest of my applets.

I thought I just need to right click and then go to "Minimize All Windows" settings but there's only one tickable option which says "alternately iconify/shade and raise", but it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

So is there a way to change a panel applet's icon? Maybe manually?
I'm using Lubuntu 17.10 and LXPanel 0.9.3 for LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

copy any icon you like from `/usr/share/icons/` to `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/images/`

add it to `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/gtkrc`

```
style "wincmd"
{
   engine "pixmap" {
      image {
         function = FLAT_BOX
         file     = "images/your-image.png"
         border   = { 4, 4, 4, 4 }
         stretch  = TRUE
      }
   }
}
```

see [here](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel_Theming) and [here](https://git.lxde.org/gitweb/?p=lxde/lxpanel.git;a=blob;f=README;h=64e23b92fb8f25169840eacdd337c4b036953c48;hb=HEAD#l40) for more